# Generate a pdf with images on header and footer with iText

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am looking forward to create a pdf using iText. 
The pdf will have a header and a footer. Both the header and footer will have a image (company logo) in it.

I am looking forward to an example similar to that. I will be using the iText library for the first time so I am not sure where to start off from.

Comment: Which iText version are you using? In particular, are you using a 7.x or a 5.x version?

Comment: Using 7x version

Comment: Does my answer help? Or are there still open issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add headers and footers to a PDF you generate using iText 7.x, you will generally create event listeners for page starts and/or page ends and add the header and footer contents there-in.

For example you can do it like in [this sample on the iText site](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/pdfhtml-header-and-footer-example). Here two event listeners are defined:

```java
//Header event handler
protected class Header implements IEventHandler {
    String header;
    public Header(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        //Retrieve document and
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
                page.getLastContentStream(), page.getResources(), pdf);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
        canvas.setFontSize(18f);
        //Write text at position
        canvas.showTextAligned(header,
                pageSize.getWidth() / 2,
                pageSize.getTop() - 30, TextAlignment.CENTER);
    }
}
```

This event handler adds a simple constant string as header to the current page. Similarly you can also add an image.

```java
//page X of Y 
protected class PageXofY implements IEventHandler {
    protected PdfFormXObject placeholder;
    protected float side = 20;
    protected float x = 300;
    protected float y = 25;
    protected float space = 4.5f;
    protected float descent = 3;
    public PageXofY(PdfDocument pdf) {
        placeholder =
                new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, side, side));
    }
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        int pageNumber = pdf.getPageNumber(page);
        Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
                page.getLastContentStream(), page.getResources(), pdf);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
                .add("Page ").add(String.valueOf(pageNumber)).add(" of");
        canvas.showTextAligned(p, x, y, TextAlignment.RIGHT);
        pdfCanvas.addXObject(placeholder, x + space, y - descent);
        pdfCanvas.release();
    }
    public void writeTotal(PdfDocument pdf) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(placeholder, pdf);
        canvas.showTextAligned(String.valueOf(pdf.getNumberOfPages()),
                0, descent, TextAlignment.LEFT);
    }
}
```

This event handler is a bit more complex, it adds a *Page **x** of **y*** footer to the current page. As the total number of pages ***y*** is unknown at the time, a reference to a placeholder XObject is added instead, and as soon as you know all the pages are created, you can call `writeTotal` to have this method write the current number of document pages into the placeholder XObject.

You register these event listeners as following:

```java
PdfWriter writer= new PdfWriter(pdfDest);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);

//Create event-handlers
String header = "pdfHtml Header and footer example using page-events";
Header headerHandler = new Header(header);
PageXofY footerHandler = new PageXofY(pdfDocument);

//Assign event-handlers
pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE,headerHandler);
pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE,footerHandler);

//Add content
[... here you add the regular page content to the PdfDocument ...]

//Write the total number of pages to the placeholder and close the document
footerHandler.writeTotal(pdfDocument);
pdfDocument.close();
```

(The actual example adds the regular page content based on HTML using pdfHTML. You may do so, too, or you may generate the content directly using `Document`, `Paragraph`, `Text`, and other layout classes.)