# Add Image at the end of pdf in Itext7

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext7

I want to add Image **at the end of the pdf where content ends** and not at the bottom of the last page. I tried using this example [Generate a pdf with images on header and footer with iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239771/generate-a-pdf-with-images-on-header-and-footer-with-itext?rq=1) but this example usage text and also this adds text at the footer

My code is as follows:

```
    File image = new File(fullFilePathNameHeader);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(image);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bis = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    
    int i;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    while ((i = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        bis.write(data, 0, i);
    }
    bis.flush();
    is.close();
    
    ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(bis.toByteArray());
    Image pdfImg = new Image(imageData);
    
            
    PageSize ps = pdfDocument.getDefaultPageSize();
    Document doc=new Document(pdfDocument);
    
    pdfImg.setFixedPosition(doc.getLeftMargin(), doc.getBottomMargin(), ps.getWidth() - doc.getLeftMargin() - doc.getRightMargin());  
//Tried above but this displays pdf at the bottom of the last page
   
    doc.add(pdfImg);
    doc.close();
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Update:
Please note, I am using below library and not lowgie one (I am mentioning it to avoid any confusion)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I have tried adding a text "EndOfTheDocument" as a placeholder in the pdf and then try to count the line till the function finds that word as below:

```
        int numPages = pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();
        boolean found = false;
        int totalLinesInDoc =0;
        for (int k = 1; k <= numPages; k--) {
           // String textOut = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfDocument.getPage(k));
            String textOut = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfDocument.getPage(k), new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
            String[] lines = textOut.split("\\r?\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {

                if ("end".equalsIgnoreCase(lines[j])) {
                     found = true;
                    System.out.println("matched line " + j);
                    break;
                }
                totalLinesInDoc++;
            }
            if(found){
                break;
            }
        }
        pdfImg.setPaddingTop(totalLinesInDoc);
        pdfImg.setHeight(totalLinesInDoc);
        pdfImg.setPageNumber(numPages);
```

pdf generate is dynamic , I was testing for a pdf which had two pages.For first page, it threw below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Determinant is zero. Cannot invert transformation
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.ParserGraphicsState.transformPoints(ParserGraphicsState.java:206)
```

While for second page, it is giving me correct number of lines.

Any suggestions on this , why it is giving error and pointers if anything needs to be corrected in above code. Having tough time working with this library as this is my very first time :(

Thank you

Update 3:
I am using below Itext librares.Please let me know if they are compatible with each other. Thanks.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>itext</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.12</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- iText pdfHTML add-on -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: anybody here, any link will also help.

Comment: The difficulty is getting the position where the content ends. You can use `pdfRender` add-on to first render the last page into an image, then scan the image from bottom to the top until you find the place where there is something else except the background, and from there you can calculate the position where your content ends.

Comment: Hello Alexey, Thank you for your  comment. Any code sample will help here.I have triwd one thing and updated my question, please check if that is viable option to achieve to get the total line number and set the image after that. Thank you.

Comment: I see you are using an old version (`7.1.2`). Could you update to the latest one (`7.1.12`) and try again? If the problem persists we would need your PDF file for analysis because the problem happens inside of iText during content parsing

Comment: Thank you Alexey for pointing that out.I have updated my question with other Itext library version, can you please check if they are compatible with each other?

Comment: You should use `html2pdf 3.0.1` but otherwise it's okay even though I'm not sure why you want to use three different iText versions in your app

Comment: ok, let me change them all and try

Comment: Hello Alexey, I have update libraries and now got total line numbers. But how can I use this information to show the image after 2-3 lines of last line. Any methods?